# Question about the definition of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, definition

This might be a stupid question, but since a topology on a set $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$, $\tau$, where for each element, $U \in \tau$, $U$ is an open set, and since there is also the requirement $X\in \tau$, how does this work where $X$ is a closed set like $[0, 1]$?

Also, since the complement of an open set is a closed set, does $X^c \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: It is common to speak of a space $X$ but a space is actually the pair $(X,\tau)$. If $(Y,\tau')$ is a space and $X\subset Y$ then we can have a space $(X,\tau)$ where $\tau$ may or may not have anything to do with $\tau'....$  Also, if $X\subset Y$ and $\tau =\{X\cap T : T\in  \tau'\},$ it is common to say "$X$ is a subspace of $Y$", although we really should say $(X,\tau)$ is a subspace of $(Y,\tau').$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong about the definition of topological space. Such a space is a pair $(X,\tau)$, where $X$ is a set and $\tau$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, for which certain conditions must hold ($\emptyset,X\in\tau$ and $X$ is stable with respect to arbitrary unions and to finite intersections). Only *after* that we define open sets. It's just this: the open sets of a topological space $(X,\tau)$ are the elements of $\tau$. Besides, the closed sets are those $Y\subset C$ such that $Y^\complement\in\tau$.

So, yes, we can perfectly define topologies $\tau$ on $\mathbb R$ for which $[0,1]$ is an open set. And for such a space, $[0,1]$ may be or not a closed set.

By the way, keep in mind that “open” is *not* the opposite of “closed”: a subset of a topological space may be open and closed at the same time (the whole space and the empty set, for instance) and may also be neither open nor closed.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, we're defining closed sets as sets whose compliments are elements of $\tau$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.